# Possible deploy docker image to AWS ECS without "stop-task"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, .net-core, amazon-ecs

Does anyone know how I could deploy docker image WITHOUT downtime on AWS ECS ?
Here is my workable script with downtime version,

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ecr="{accountId}.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
repo="${ecr}/jobapp"
configuration="Debug"
version="1.0.0.0"
endpoint="{url}"
pat="{pat}"

docker build \
  --build-arg CONFIGURATION=${configuration} \
  --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=${version} \
  --build-arg ENDPOINT=${endpoint} \
  --build-arg PAT=${pat} \
  . -t ${repo}:${configuration}-${version} -t ${repo}:${configuration}-latest -f Dockerfile

echo $(aws ecr get-authorization-token --region us-west-2 --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2) | docker login -u AWS ${ecr} --password-stdin

docker push ${repo}:${configuration}-${version} && docker push ${repo}:${configuration}-latest

#stop service, TODO: downtime will happen here
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster jobapp-ecs-dev | jq -r ".taskArns[]" | awk '{print "aws ecs stop-task --cluster jobapp-ecs-dev --task \""$0"\""}' | sh

#run service with latest docker image
aws ecs run-task --cluster jobapp-ecs-dev --task-definition jobapp-task:1
```

Btw, the ECS configures to desire 1 node, min 1 node, and max 2 nodes as its cluster settings. And there is a ELB, and a Task definition behind. I've wrapped it all and run for months. The only problem is downtime so I have to run and test script in the mid-night. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

No downtime is a feature of "blue-green" deployment practices...

From Martin Fowler's 2010 [post](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) about it..

> The blue-green deployment approach does this by ensuring you have two
>   production environments, as identical as possible. At any time one of
>   them, let's say blue for the example, is live. As you prepare a new
>   release of your software you do your final stage of testing in the
>   green environment. Once the software is working in the green
>   environment, you switch the router so that all incoming requests go to
>   the green environment - the blue one is now idle.

AWS's elastic beanstalk includes support for [Blue-Green deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/blue-green-deployment/), with a slightly different execution.

> The CI/CD pipeline architecture creates a clone (green) of the live
>   Elastic Beanstalk environment (blue). The pipeline then swaps the URLs
>   between the two environments.
>
> While CodePipeline deploys application code to the original
>   environment—and testing and maintenance take place—the temporary clone
>   environment handles the live traffic. Once deployment to the blue
>   environment is successful, and code review and code testing are done,
>   the pipeline again swaps the URLs between the green and blue
>   environments. The blue environment starts serving the live traffic
>   again, and the pipeline terminates the green environment.

Comment: Elastic beanstalk is good. But is there a practice using native ECS ?  Blue-green sounds a fundamental concept for all cloud services. Just curious is there a more friendly way.

Comment: Blue-Green is fundamental to the way you deploy.  ECS is only concerned about execution.  So no, ECS doesn't have anything built-in.

Comment: Understood, still got some clues now. Many thanks !